# Getting text from a WPF combobox or text box in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am using a Grid to hold text boxes and combo boxes. I want to get the selected item from the combo boxes and the text from the text boxes. Is there a way to do this without having to cast the UIElement as Combo or Text box. Below is how I am currently doing this.

```
foreach (UIElement field in _fields)
{

    string val="";
    if (field is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox bx = field as TextBox;
        val=bx.Text;
    }
    else if (field is ComboBox)
    {
        ComboBox bx = field as ComboBox;
        val=bx.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: With the MVVM pattern you would have a view model that stays in sync with the data in the window/page which means you never need to reach into the actual controls. What is the purpose of this code? Seems like `val` will just always have the value of the last control that is looped over.

Comment: I will try and explain, basically I am developing a sort of text file editor that needs specific syntax. There is a section of the file with 6-11 fields separated by a ':', some fields can have a number of options hence the combo box, others just need a name or a string value. There is a function to validate the syntax of the file. The code above simply goes through each line the user has entered, gets the text and creates a file object for the validation function.  val is just the data I want to add to the file object

Answer (score 1):

The best way to access data in WPF is to use databinding or even use MVVM. A quick and dirty way could be to give your elements a name by assigning x:Name in your XAML. Then you do not need to cast the elements in code behind.